# Configure cron-apt to use smtp relay

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, email

I've setup cron-apt on Ubuntu 14.04.3 to automate updates. I'd like it to email notifications and have configured MAILTO="user@example.com", and MAILON="upgrade" options in /etc/cron-apt/config. I have an smtp relay running on another server, how do I configure cron-apt to send email using this smtp relay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the following error when the email was trying to send 'Cannot start "/usr/sbin/sendmail": executable not found (adjust *sendmail* variable)'. The fix for this is to install SSMTP and edit /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf to point to your smtp relay.

This is a good guide on how to set this up http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=56312 .